# mod_wsgi Loads Module But Not WSGI File

Tags: python, mod-wsgi, windows-7-x64, wsgi, apache2.4

**My Environment (All 32 Bit)**

- Apache 2.4 (via XAMPP)
- Python 2.7.6
- mod_wsgi 3.4 for Apache 2.4
- Windows 7 64Bit

**http.config**

- LoadModule wsgi_module modules/mod_wsgi.so
- WSGIScriptAlias \application C:\xampp\htdocs\site\wsgi\wsgi_app.wsgi (VirtualHost)
- AddHandler wsgi-script .wsgi (VirtualHost)

**Apache Error Log (Last Entries After Apache Restart)**

- [Fri Mar 21 16:22:59.679443 2014] [:info] [pid 7160:tid 440] mod_wsgi (pid=7160): Initializing Python.
- [Fri Mar 21 16:22:59.705445 2014] [:info] [pid 7160:tid 440] mod_wsgi (pid=7160): Attach interpreter ''.

From what I can tell, WSGIPythonPath is only needed if extra directories need searching/the directory of the wsgi file shouldn't, so don't understand why plain text is all that appears in Chrome?

This was accomplished by the [Google Documentation](https://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/).

Regards

Comment: Don't use backslashes for path separators in the Apache configuration, use POSIX style forward slashes. Not sure anything will work if you use backslashes. You also don't need the AddHandler when using WSGIScriptAlias, so don't mix them. And mod_wsgi has got nothing to do with Google, so it isn't the Google documentation you are referring to but the mod_wsgi documentation. BTW, also indicate what URL you are using. You have things mounted at a sub URL, but are you even using the matching URL.

Comment: Hi Graham.  You're right, wasn't loading the correct URL: Apache set to: 

WSGIScriptAlias /application C:/xampp/htdocs/site/wsgi/mod_wsgi.wsgi 

and browsing to: 

http://localhost/site/wsgi/application 

gives 404 Object Not Found!  The entire .wsgi's has: 

def application(environ, start_response):
    status = '200 OK'
    output = 'Hello World!'

    response_headers = [('Content-type', 'text/plain'),
                        ('Content-Length', str(len(output)))]
    start_response(status, response_headers)

    return [output]
 
Is the web framework needed for this wsgi to work? Regards

Comment: You should be using 'http://localhost/application'.